# Angular 8 app produces runtime error in console related to ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, angular8, ng-bootstrap

I have an Angular 8 app that's been happily using `ng-bootstrap`. After implementation of `ng-bootstrap` in my dashboard lazy module, I'm facing a problem which is I'm unable to use `Dropdown` Component.

Can someone help me to find out how this problem will solve?

**Re-Edit**

Now, I've below folder structure:

[image]

and by following [This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4nqsgp?file=main.ts) example. I've created a new folder named `dropdown`.

Here is my dashboard.component.html:

```
<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="p-2 flex-grow-1">
        <h4>
          Dashboard
          <span class="badge badge-light">Transactions</span>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="p-2">
        <ngbd-dropdown-basic></ngbd-dropdown-basic>
    </div>
</div>
```

dashboard.module.ts:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard.component';
import { NgbdDropdownBasicModule } from '../dropdown/dropdown-basic.module';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: DashboardComponent }
];


@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, NgbdDropdownBasicModule,                                                                     RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [NgbdDropdownBasicModule ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

dropdown-basic.html:

```
<div ngbDropdown class="dropdown">
  <button ngbDropdownToggle class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

dropdown-basic.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'ngbd-dropdown-basic',
    templateUrl: './dropdown-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdDropdownBasic {}
```

dropdown-basic.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { NgbdDropdownBasic } from './dropdown-basic';


@NgModule({
    imports: [NgbModule],
    declarations: [NgbdDropdownBasic],
    exports: [NgbdDropdownBasic],
    bootstrap: [NgbdDropdownBasic]
})
export class NgbdDropdownBasicModule { }
```

Now, the current issue is my `ngbd-dropdown-basic` loaded successfully, but not showing it's content.

[image]

What I'm doing wrong please let me know. :(

Comment: You are ading a directive (NgbDropdown) into the imports of your module. That's incorrect. Modules can import other modules, not directives.

Comment: I have also tried to import ngbmodule to my imports and then there is no error in console also dropdown not working. If you have running code example of dropdown component then post it here.

Comment: Your html should work if you have proper imports now. If your code is still not working, double check if you have extra bootstrap imports, `ng-bootstrap` doesn't need addition imports like <link> or <script> or in your angular.json.  [Example with your code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4nqsgp?file=app/dropdown-basic.html)

Comment: @terahertz have a look on my edited post.

Comment: @JBNizet kindly check my edited post may be now you can help me what I'm doing wrong in my code.

Comment: Why do you add NgbdDropdownBasicModule to the providers of your module? providers is for services. Not for modules. ANyway, if you want help, post a reproduction of your issue in a stackblitz.

Comment: I want to see app.module.ts, can you just import NgbdDropdownBasicModule in your app.module.ts?

Comment: @JBNizet I've found what I want. Kindly check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally achieved my goal by

removing:
`providers: [NgbdDropdownBasicModule ]`

and adding

`declarations: [DashboardComponent]` in my `dashboard.module.ts` file.

Appreciate time and efforts of other developers on my post.